# Fastest way to chunk and calculate sum, min, max in a 70 GB csv file

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have a 70 GB csv file (`data.csv`) that has the following structure `Timestamp,Price,Volume`.

```
1649289600174,100,100
1649289600176,105,100
1649289600178,109,100
1649289600179,104,100
1649289600181,101,100
1649289600182,100,100
1649289600188,90,100
```

I can read line by line like this using python.

```
with open("data.csv") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        row = line.split(",")
        current_price = row[1]
```

If the prices moves `+10` or `-10`, then I would like to take a snapshot of that chunk and calculate open, close, high, low values for those prices. Also `volume_sum` for the volume. In the above sample, price moves from 100 to 90.

- `open` is the **first** price found in the chunk. In the above sample it is `100`
- `close` is the **last** price found in the chunk. In the above sample it is `90`
- `high` is the **max(price)** found in the chunk. In the above sample it is `109`
- `low` is the **min(price)** found in the chunk. In the above sample it is `90`
- `volume_sum` is the **sum(volume)** found in the chunk. In the above sample it is `700`

These open, close, high, low, volume_sum becomes a new record. The new chunk will be measured from the `close` price, which is 90. i.e. If the price goes to 100 or goes to 80, that would become a new chunk.

I'm on Ubuntu. Since, I have a very large file, I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this. [I don't want to use pandas for this. It is slow for my use case]

Can someone guide me?

Thanks

Comment: With that amount of data, think about moving it into a database.

Comment: @glennjackman I use Google Colab to process the data. Also it is a one time process. So I'm not looking for a persistent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- first chunk starts with the price found in the first row
- when switching chunks the volume of the corresponding 'switch' row is not counted in the new chunk
- though not mentioned in the question/description, we'll also provide the open/close times for each chunk
- ouput format: `openTime,closeTime,openPrc,closePrc,highPrc,lowPrc,volume`
- when we reach the end of the file go ahead and print out the last chunk regardless of whether or not we crossed the `+/- 10` theshold (and assuming there are at least 2 data rows in the last chunk)

Adding a few more lines to the input:

```
$ cat data.csv
1649289600174,100,100
1649289600176,105,100
1649289600178,109,100
1649289600179,104,100
1649289600181,101,100
1649289600182,100,100
1649289600188,90,100
1649289600190,83,90
1649289600288,95,60
1649289600388,79,35
1649289600488,83,100
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v mvDN=-10 -v mvUP=10 '

function print_stats() {
    if (openTime && openTime != closeTime)
       print openTime,closeTime,openPrc,closePrc,highPrc,lowPrc,volume

    openTime=closeTime
    openPrc=highPrc=lowPrc=closePrc
    volume=( NR==1 ? currVol : 0 )
}

BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
      { closeTime=$1
        currPrc=$2
        currVol=$3

        closePrc=currPrc
        volume+=currVol
        highPrc=(currPrc > highPrc ? currPrc : highPrc)
        lowPrc= (currPrc < lowPrc  ? currPrc : lowPrc)

        if ( (currPrc - openPrc <= mvDN) || (currPrc - openPrc >= mvUP) )
           print_stats()
      }
END   { print_stats() }
' data.csv
```

This generates:

```
1649289600174,1649289600188,100,90,109,90,700
1649289600188,1649289600388,90,79,95,79,185
1649289600388,1649289600488,79,83,83,79,100
```

Comment: Hi, just tested your solution and it seems like this is the fastest solution. However, I see empty `high` values in some instances. Could it be fixed? Thanks

Comment: `when switching chunks the volume of the corresponding 'switch' row is counted twice (once in the previous chunk, once in the next chunk)`. I think we shouldn't count twice.

Comment: Any idea why it prints empty value for `high` . I even see empty value in your 2nd row sample output.

Comment: In second row, the high value should be `95`. Not empty value. Thanks

Comment: found the issue. Looks like there is a typo. It should be `highPrc` instead of `highPr`. Thanks

Comment: @John went ahead and pulled the 'duplicate' volume from the new chunk

Answer (score 2):

As others said, use a database or some other tools like Spark if you want to do this. 70GB is a lot. That being said, you can just iterate over the lines, keep track of the relevant values in a dictionary buffer and then write and empty the buffer when you find the relevant differences. You should pack all of this in a class but the gist of it is the following:

```
def convert(tup):
    tup = tup.split(",")
    return tup[0], int(tup[1]), int(tup[2])


def write_buffer(buffer, close_price, min_price, max_price, close_stamp, volume_sum):
    buffer["close_price"] = close_price
    buffer["min_price"] = min_price
    buffer["max_price"] = max_price
    buffer["close_stamp"] = close_stamp
    buffer["volume_sum"] = volume_sum


def buffer_to_file(buffer, path_to_file):
    # Ensure insertion order of keys
    keys = [
        "open_stamp",
        "open",
        "close_price",
        "min_price",
        "max_price",
        "volume_sum",
        "close_stamp",
    ]
    with open(path_to_file, "w") as f:
        for k in keys[:-1]:
            f.write(f"{buffer[k]}, ")
        f.write(f"{buffer[keys[-1]]}")  # do not write the last val with a comma
        f.write("\n")  # new line for each buffer write


in_path = "read-large-file.txt"
out_path = "out.txt"


def compute_stats(in_path, out_path):
    with open(in_path) as f:
        time, open_p, vol = convert(f.readline())
        min_p, max_p, volume_sum = open_p, open_p, vol
        buffer = {"open_stamp": time, "open": open_p}
        for line in f:
            t, p, v = convert(line)
            volume_sum += v
            if p > max_p:
                max_p = p
            if p < min_p:
                min_p = p
            if abs(p - open_p) >= 10:
                write_buffer(buffer, p, min_p, max_p, t, volume_sum)
                buffer_to_file(buffer, out_path)
                # Reset buffer and values
                min_p, max_p, volume_sum = p, p, v
                buffer = {"open_stamp": t, "open": p}


compute_stats(in_path, out_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no much you can do as you need to read all the lines. Python I/O is better than it was, but it does not match low level languages like C or Rust or AWK.

One thing you can do is use bigger memory chunk, you may also want to try to work with bytes. maybe you can find a way to split the job in smaller chunk and use async or mp.

Anyway 70GB file is huge.